# How can I use an encrypted connection string with Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

In my project with entity framework, I connect to the database through the connectionStrings in the App.config. No problem.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ParametrosEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Busine...." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Now, the BusinessEntities class use to connect the string

```
public partial class ParametrosEntities : DbContext
{
    public ParametrosEntities()
        : base("ParametrosEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

Now, what I am doing is to encrypt the connection url for safety, but this is where I dont know how to let EntityFramewor the Connection string changed. I explain.

App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name=" ParametrosEntitiesMDM" connectionString="FGDHTYEHSN58302..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then i created a new class to decrypt

```
 public class ServDbContext : DbContext
{
   public ServDbContext(string sNameOrStringConnection)
    {
        new DbContext(GetConnection(sNameOrStringConnection));
    }

    public static string GetConnection(string nameStrg)
    {
        bool bFlag = false;
        var conexion = Desencriptar(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nameStrg].ConnectionString, out bFlag);
        if (bFlag)
            return conexion;
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

and finally my BusinessEntities changed to

```
public partial class ParametrosEntities : ServDbContext
{
    public ParametrosEntities()
        : base("ParametrosEntitiesMDM")
    {
    }
}
```

and that gives the error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification     starting at index 0.

and cant connect.

Comment: Who are you encrypting it against? If someone has control over your dll then they can just fire it up and look through fiddler what outbound connections are established.

Comment: in fact, I'm not encrypted, i just decrypted in ServDbContext class through a DLL

Comment: Depth in defense is an appropriate security measure. Regardless of "no one should be on the server anyway" arguments.

Comment: Have you followed these steps @Makito? [Provided by Microsoft?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx)